# How to escape url encoding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, decode, encode

I am creating a link that creates URL parameters that contains links with URL parameters. 
The issue is that I have a link like this

```
http://mydomain/_layouts/test/MyLinksEdit.aspx?auto=true&source=
    http://vtss-sp2010hh:8088/AdminReports/helloworld.aspx?pdfid=193
&url=http://vtss-sp2010hh:8088/AdminReports/helloworld.aspx?pdfid=193%26pdfname=5.6%20Upgrade
&title=5.6 Upgrade
```

This link goes to a bookmark adding page where it reads these parameters.

`auto` is wheather to read the following parameters or not

`source` is where to go after you finish adding or cancelling

`url` is the bookmark link

`title` is the name of the bookmark

The values of `url` and `title` get entered into 2 fields. Then the user has to click `save` or `cancel`.
The problem is when the bookmark page enters the values into the field, it will decode them.
Then if you try to save, it will won't let you save because the `pdfname` value in the `url` value has a space in it. It needs the link to not have any spaces. So basically, I want it so that after it enters it in the field, it will still be a `%20` instead of a space.

There isn't a problem with `source`, `auto`, or `title`, just the `url`...

Is there a way to solve this? Like maybe a special escape character I can use for the `%20`?

**Note: I cannot modify the bookmark page.**

I am using c#/asp.net to create the link and go to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 44):

Since .NET Framework 4.5 you can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode`.

It resides in `System.dll`, so it does not require any additional references.

It properly escapes characters for URLs, unlike `Uri.EscapeUriString`

It does not have any limits on the length of the string, unlike `Uri.EscapeDataString`, so it can be used for POST requests

```
 System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(urlText)
```

Another option is

```
 System.Uri.EscapeDataString()
```

Comment: I tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx, but it just encoding it like with a `+`, which didn't work, because the bookmark page, decoded it. But i figured it out, I just did, `string.replace(" ", "%2520");`. This way the bookmark page decodes `%25` into a `%`, which leaves just `%20` left which is what worked.

Answer (score 7):

Uri.EscapeDataString() and Uri.UnescapeDataString() are safe comparing to UrlEncode/UrlDecode methods and does not convert plus characters into spaces when decoding.

Some details from another user: http://geekswithblogs.net/mikehuguet/archive/2009/08/16/134123.aspx

Comment: Please explain your answer. At the moment what you have said is subjective because you don't explain why. Why are they safe...please elaborate for the question author.

Comment: Comparing to UrlEncode/UrlDecode methods, Uri.EscapeDataString/Uri.UnescapeDataString does not convert plus characters into spaces. (I edited my post to clarify answer)

Answer (score 4):

Just use HttpUtilty's `UrlEncode` method right before you hand off the url;

```
 string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
```